# python multiprocessing Barrier with unknown number of remote processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, barrier

I'm using Manager objects to run multiprocessing over a cluster and I want to setup a Barrier to synchronise all my processes, but I won't know in advance how many processes I will spawn across the cluster (my client process uses some logic to determine how many to make based on available cpus and ram).

Since I'm setting up the Manager by subclassing BaseManager and registering the Barrier object with the class before I create the manager (as per the example in the docs), I have to specify the number of parties when I instantiate the Barrier, but I don't know at that point what the total number of parties will be.

```
barrier = threading.Barrier(parties=?)
class ClusterManager(BaseManager): pass
ClusterManager.register('get_barrier', callable=lambda:barrier)
manager = ClusterManager(etc etc)
```

What I really want is to be able to create a Barrier object (with an arbitrary number of parties) and then change the parties attribute after the fact, once I know how many remote processes have been launched, but if I try and do that with the built-in Barrier object (e.g. `barrier.parties += 1`) I get `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

My current hacky solution is to use a Queue object and have each remote process launched put something in that Queue once each, so the qsize is equal to the total number of processes. I then later use task_done and join calls on the queue to achieve my sync point. Unfortunately there are lots of ways this method can fail.

Is there some better way of achieving what I want, preferably using only the standard library?

Comment: As `.Barrier` is inherited from `threading.Barrier` you should use `multiprocessing.Barrier` which have a additional `wrapper`. Show your statement that raises:. `AttributeError: can't set attribute.`.

Comment: I added an example in the question. Whether I use the Barrier object from threading or multiprocessing (which are [exactly the same](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier)) makes no impact on the question I'm asking.

Comment: You can implement your own `Barrier` using `Condition` and `Lock` but `Queue` is essentially the same functionality.

Comment: ***"added an example"***: Your example is **PSEYDOCODE**, not [mcve], can't reproduce `AttributeError:`.  ***"exactly the same"***: Compare the source code, **it is not**. ***"makes no impact on the question"***: I didn't tell otherwise. You have to use `barrier._parties += 1`

Comment: Changing the number of parties without a lock isn't thread-safe even if it doesn't throw `AttributeError`.

Comment: @Jason ***"isn't thread-safe"***: The OP uses `Process`, not `Thread`. ***"without a lock"***: It's already locked using: `with self._cond:`.